# Library import in Python does not work as expected

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am having a strange error executing this Python code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(2,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'),
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mae',
              metrics=['mse'])
model.summary()
```

resulting in the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

( I already tried the same code on google Colab and it works ).

The strange thing for me is that this code instead works without errors on the same machine ( this means that all libraries are there ):

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential([
  Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and, if in a jupyter notebook I execute first the second version and than the first one, I do not encounter errors.

What can be the cause of such behavior and how to fix it ? I am using Python 3.9.7 with miniconda.

UPDATE 1: this behavior seems to go away when downgrading from tensorflow 2.6.0 to tensorflow 2.4.1 .

UPDATE 2: complete traceback as requested:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_19355/718649126.py in <module>
----> 1 model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      2   tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
      3   tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
      4 ])
      5 

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py in __getattr__(self, item)
     60 
     61   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 62     module = self._load()
     63     return getattr(module, item)
     64 

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py in _load(self)
     43     """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     44     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 45     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     46     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     47 

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Comment: This might help. [Another SO query on Keras import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262955/how-to-import-keras-from-tf-keras-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Thank you. At the moment I have the feeling that it is the fault of the version of tensorflow.

Comment: This problem was solved when downgrading from tensorflow 2.6.0 to tensorflow 2.4.1 . I will leave anyway the question in case somebody understand what is happening.

Comment: You should add the complete traceback, the error is meaningless without its context.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy done . Maybe you understand what was happening

Comment: The problem is actually quite simple, latest versions of tf.keras are built on top of keras (partially reversing the integration of keras inside tensorflow), so to use tf.keras on those versions, you also need to install the standalone keras package.

Comment: Thank you! But than how do you explain that the second method worked on the same machine? In theory I am loading same stuff...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there's a bug in the current version of tensorflow, particularly with the `_load()` method in the `LazyLoader` class defined in the module `tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader`. I think we could just leave it until being fixed. I'd like to dig into another question raised here: how come your second segment of codes worked yet the first one failed?

The reason comes from the import system as well as the dot operator in Python.

In the statement `import m1.m2.m3` or `from m1.m2.m3 import n1`, the dot notation in `m1.m2.m3` is used to separate names of modules(packages) and submodules(subpackages). It's not a real dot operator. When processing this statement, Python will first import the module(package) `m1`, then `m1.m2`, then `m1.m2.m3`. In each step of loading the modules, two notable side-effects occur(among lots of other actions):

- the to-be-imported package's `__init__.py` file is executed.
- a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object. For this example, `m1.__dict__['m2']` is set to be the module object `m1.m2`, and `m1.m2.__dict__['m3']` is set to be the module object `m1.m2.m3`.

And for the real dot operator, for example an expression `obj1.attr1`, the evaluation order will be:

1. evaluate `obj1.__getattribute__('attr1')` and return the value
2. if no such an attribute found in the first step, then evaluate `odj1.__getattr__('attr1')`

where the search of `obj1.__dict__['attr1']` is launched in the first step.

Back to tensorflow, there's such a statement in `__init__.py` under the package `tensorflow`:

```
keras = _LazyLoader("keras", globals(), _keras_module)
```

Here's a simplified "second version" of your sample as below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
# tensorflow.__dict__['keras'] is set to be the module tensorflow.keras
import tensorflow as tf # make the module name tensorflow useable

print(type(tf.keras)) # tf.keras is evaluated to the submodule tensorflow.keras
# output: <class 'module'>
```

It turns out the name binding to the submodule object overwrites the binding(assignment) in `__init__.py`.

But if we don't import the submodule `tensorflow.keras`, then the binding in `__init__.py` works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(type(tf.keras))
# output: <class 'tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader.LazyLoader'>
```

That explains why your second method worked but the first one failed.

---

Reference:

For import mechanism:

- [7.11. The import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import)
- [5. The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

For dot operator:

- [Descriptor HowTo Guide - Invocation from an instance](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invocation-from-an-instance)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from tensorflow import keras` and try again executing the same code.

if it shows the same error again then run below code in `jupyter notebook`:

```
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)
```

if you find some differences in versions, then execute below code in `jupyter notebook` which will automatically install upgraded and compatible version of tensorflow and keras along with its other required libraries.

```
!pip insatll tensorflow
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)

!pip install keras
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

Let us know if issue still persists.