# Error: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing the code for building extraction using deep learning but when I am trying to import the library files, it is showing the error "No module named 'tensorflow.keras'". I am unable to resolve it. Can anyone help?

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from patchify import patchify
from PIL import Image
import segmentation_models as sm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

from tensorflow.keras.metrics import MeanIoU
```

My current version of tensorflow is - 2.9.1 and version of keras is - 2.2.0

The error that I am getting is:-

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\segmentation_models\__init__.py:98, in <module>
     97 try:
---> 98     set_framework(_framework)
     99 except ImportError:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\segmentation_models\__init__.py:67, in set_framework(name)
     66 if name == _KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME:
---> 67     import keras
     68     import efficientnet.keras  # init custom objects

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py:3, in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py:25, in <module>
     24 from .np_utils import normalize
---> 25 from .multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py:7, in <module>
      5 from __future__ import print_function
----> 7 from ..layers.merge import concatenate
      8 from .. import backend as K

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py:4, in <module>
      3 from ..utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
----> 4 from ..engine.base_layer import Layer
      5 from ..engine import Input

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\__init__.py:8, in <module>
      7 from .network import get_source_inputs
----> 8 from .training import Model

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:21, in <module>
     20 from .training_utils import weighted_masked_objective
---> 21 from . import training_arrays
     22 from . import training_generator

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py:14, in <module>
     13 from .. import backend as K
---> 14 from .. import callbacks as cbks
     15 from ..utils.generic_utils import Progbar

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py:18, in <module>
     17 from collections import OrderedDict
---> 18 from collections import Iterable
     19 from .utils.generic_utils import Progbar

ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' (C:\Users\DOLONCHAPA\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\collections\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 8>()
      6 from patchify import patchify
      7 from PIL import Image
----> 8 import segmentation_models as sm
      9 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
     11 from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\segmentation_models\__init__.py:101, in <module>
     99 except ImportError:
    100     other = _TF_KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME if _framework == _KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME else _KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME
--> 101     set_framework(other)
    103 print('Segmentation Models: using `{}` framework.'.format(_KERAS_FRAMEWORK))
    105 # import helper modules

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\segmentation_models\__init__.py:71, in set_framework(name)
     69 elif name == _TF_KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME:
     70     from tensorflow import keras
---> 71     import efficientnet.tfkeras  # init custom objects
     72 else:
     73     raise ValueError('Not correct module name `{}`, use `{}` or `{}`'.format(
     74         name, _KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME, _TF_KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME))

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\efficientnet\tfkeras.py:6, in <module>
      2 from . import model
      4 from .preprocessing import center_crop_and_resize
----> 6 EfficientNetB0 = inject_tfkeras_modules(model.EfficientNetB0)
      7 EfficientNetB1 = inject_tfkeras_modules(model.EfficientNetB1)
      8 EfficientNetB2 = inject_tfkeras_modules(model.EfficientNetB2)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\efficientnet\__init__.py:50, in inject_tfkeras_modules(func)
     49 def inject_tfkeras_modules(func):
---> 50     import tensorflow.keras as tfkeras
     51     @functools.wraps(func)
     52     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
     53         kwargs['backend'] = tfkeras.backend

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
```

Comment: [may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262955/how-to-import-keras-from-tf-keras-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Shishu Kumar Choudhary,

There is `tensorflow` and `keras` version mismatched in your system environment. (TF=2.9.1, Keras=2.2)

You need to install the same version of `keras==2.9` as installed version of `tensorflow==2.9` to fix this issue.

Please use the below code to install `keras==2.9` and try running your code again

```
!pip install keras==2.9

!pip install patchify    #To install and import other mentioned libraries  in code
!pip install segmentation_models
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicate your situation on my system and it works perfectly.

I think there is version related problem you can use this set of versions.

```
tensorflow version:          2.8.2
keras version:               2.8.0
numpy version:               1.21.6
cv2 version:                 4.6.0
segmentation_models version: 1.0.1
python version:              3.7.14
```