"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras' " in jupiter notebook
I want import in file ipynb:
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import losses

My code looks like:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import re
import shutil
import string
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import losses

But I get error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 7
      5 import string
      6 import tensorflow as tf
----> 7 from tensorflow.keras import layers
      8 from tensorflow.keras import losses

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'

I have Linux and conda environment with version tensorflow  2.17.0, python 3.10.14 and keras 3.4.1.
I was trying change version tensorflow on 2.16 and keras on 3.3, 3.2, 3.1 but it didn't work. I need use layers to tutorial on tensorflow about "Basic text classification".

Where did from tensorflow.keras import layers come from? Keras is just import keras afaik. EDIT: nvm, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47265298/13317272

Also be certain you've ran pip install --upgrade keras

@casr you have right. I don't know why on tensorflow tutorial give such that import. Thank you.

@casr give for me correct solution. I have change import from:
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import losses

to:
from keras import layers
from keras import losses

